# Telerik Reporting ReportSerializable exception

Tags: c#, .net, telerik, telerik-reporting

While running Telerik Reporting (Designer) on my MacOS in .NET6 (Web Application, KendoUI even simple MVC) I was getting an error:

```
 {"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"Type: Telerik.Reporting.ReportSerialization.V4_0.ReportSerializable`1[Telerik.Reporting.Report]","exceptionType":null,"stackTrace":null}
```

This error happens when I try to open any kind of report.

This error does not occur on Windows machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've heard from Telerik Support team is that they had some issue/known bug with one of their (graphic) libraries that was common for Windows systems. There was a workaround using Docker, but I wanted to also be able to run the application through my IDE.
The solution that worked for me, after trying all of the advices from the Telerik Support team and contacting them is to actually use new (R3) version of their software (that removed this library and now uses Skia library ).

After adding the Nuget ( Telerik ) packages for Skia. The issue was no more and I was able to use Telerik Reporting normally on MacOS too.

In my `Project.csproj` I've added (among other Telerik and Nuget packages):

```
  <ItemGroup>
    ...
    <PackageReference Include="Telerik.Drawing.Skia" Version="17.2.23.1010" />
    ...
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I reproduced this with .NET6 app under Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (WSL). The issue was gone after adding file runtimeconfig.template.json with content:

```
{
    "configProperties": {
        "System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport": true
    }
}
```

Source:
https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/knowledge-base/system-drawing-common-is-not-supported-on-non-windows-platforms

Comment: This is not enough for me ( MacOS ) no changes.